# Is it possible to capture environment variables set by an external command?

Tags: go

I have a script (on Windows) that sets a number of environment variables. I would like to execute this script in Go to set up environment variables for subsequent calls to a binary.

Something like this:

```
cmd1 := exec.Command("setup_env.bat")
cmd.Run()

// other_command.exe relies on environment variables
// set by setup_env.bat
cmd2 := exec.Command("some_binary.exe")
cmd2.Env = cmd1.Env
cmd2.Run()
```

However this doesn't work, as `cmd1.Env` is empty after calling `cmd1.Run()` (environment variables set in `cmd1` don't seem to propagate to `cmd1.Env`). `os.Environ()` also seems unaffected after calling `cmd1.Run()`.

If you're curious as to why I'm doing this, I'm trying to automate a task that normally requires the user to call `setup_env.bat` followed by `other_command.exe` in a command prompt. I do not own `setup_env.bat`, and it may change frequently, so I can't just set the environment variables myself in Go.

Comment: Create a bat file running first `setup_env.bat` and then `some_binary.exe` and call that one from Go.

Comment: The whole concept of an environment makes it impossible to do what you want. Use something along what md2perpe suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to produce the desired result with the following code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("setup_env.bat", "&&", "some_binary.exe")
cmd.Run()
```

I also discovered it's possible to manually parse the environment variables by capturing `stdout` after printing the environment with `SET`. For example:

```
func getEnv(command string) ([]string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, "&&", "SET")
    out, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    rawEnv, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(out)

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    env := strings.Split(string(rawEnv), "\r\n")
    return env[:len(env)-1], nil
}

// ...

cmd := exec.Command("some_binary.exe")
env, err := getEnv("setup_env.bat")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
cmd.Env = env // or os.Setenv(...) if you need it in current context
cmd.Run()
```